# Is function $f(x)=\frac{\text{cos}(x)}{x}$ significant?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am undertaking course in digital signal processing. I've learned during my undergraduate maths the sinc function i.e.
$$\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{x}$$
But only now I am actually doing stuff with this function and finding it relevant. Hence my question. Is the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\text{cos}(x)}{x}$$
also significant in some areas? Usually sines and cosines go hand to hand hence do we use an original name for it i.e. "cosc"? I looked for it but can't really find anything about it. No mention about it in Wiki site about sinc function either.

Comment: Unlike $\text{sinc}$ this has a singularity.

Comment: One of the main reasons that the sinc function is so useful is because it's Fourier transform is the rectangular function $\mathbb{1}_{\big[-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}\big]}$. It's a nice exercise to compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{cos(x)}{x}$. You'll see that you obtain something different, and "less useful" in the digital signals environment.

Comment: I don't know of any special applications. The "mathematical" reason sinc is special is because sin(x)/x can be continuously extended to x=0, indeed differentiably extended. I guess it has applications in signal processing but I don't know what they are. The cosine "counterpart" to sin(x)/x is probably [1-cos(x)]/x which also can be continuously extended to x=0. However I don't know of any practical applications for that function either.